# change background and text color in AlertController android

Tags: android, colors, background

How can we change the background and text color in AlertController?
Is there any way without using xml, so that we can add or modify here itself so that the color can be changed?
I was able to change color of bluetooth_discoverable but not able to change the background color in the top and down area where icon is present.

```
void createDialog(){
final AlertController.AlertParams p=mAlertParams;
p.mIconId=android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info;
p.mTitle=getString(R.string.bluetooth_permission_request);
View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bluetooth_discoverable,null);
p.mView=view;
TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message);
if (mEnableOnly) {
tv.setText(getString(R.string.bluetooth_ask_enablement));
}
else {
  v.setText(getString(R.string.bluetooth_ask_enablement_and_discovery,mTimeout));
}
p.mPositiveButtonText=getString(R.string.yes);
p.mPositiveButtonListener=this;
p.mNegativeButtonText=getString(R.string.no);
p.mNegativeButtonListener=this;
setupAlert();
}
```